# Attribution of command line parameter to multiple arguments

Tags: python, command-line-arguments, argparse

I am trying to build a command line parser that will be able to share between arguments the values passed in order to avoid having to type them multiple times. Said otherwise, I would like the namespaces of both argument to be identical:

```
import argparse

class PrintAction(argparse.Action):
    def __init__(self, option_strings, dest, **kwargs):
        super(PrintAction, self).__init__(option_strings, dest, **kwargs)

    def __call__(self, parser, namespace, values, option_string=None):
        for val in values:
            print(val)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A foo that foos and a bar that bars')
parser.add_argument('--foo', action=PrintAction)
parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='+')

args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'a', 'b', 'c']) # Case 1
args = parser.parse_args(['a', 'b', 'c']) # Case 2
```

I would then like a solution that stores in both cases `['a', 'b', 'c']` in `bar` but also that in the case that `--foo` is provided, then `a`, `b` and `c` would be printed.

For now, what I get is `foo` prints only `a` and `bar` stores only `b` and `c` in `case 1` and the correct result in `case 2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make `--foo` a boolean flag. Now it's a string parameter, because you did not state otherwise. Set [action](https://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#action) to `store_true` for the boolean flag effect.

The final solution would look like:

```
def print_args(args):
    if args.foo:
        for val in args.bar:
            print(val)

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='A foo that foos and a bar that bars')
parser.add_argument('--foo', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('bar', nargs='+')

args = parser.parse_args(['--foo', 'a', 'b', 'c']) # Case 1
args = parser.parse_args(['a', 'b', 'c']) # Case 2
```

Then calling `print_args(args)` in the first case will print `a`, `b` and `c` and in the second case, it won't.

Answer (score 1):

You can't (readily) trick the `argparse` into reusing `argv` strings.  The parser allocates values to the Actions.

The default `nargs` is `None`, which means, use the the next string as an argument.

```
parser.add_argument('--foo')
```

would set `foo='a'`, and `bar=['b','c']`.

In your Action, `values` will be `['a']`, which you print.  In `optparse` each option gets the remaining `argv` list, which it can consume as it wants.  In `argparse` it only gets the `values` that its `nargs` demands.

You could specify in the `__init__` that the `nargs=0`, and then print from `sys.argv`.  Eqivalently, as @9000 suggests, make it a `store_true` and print after parsing.  Look at the code for the `store_true` Action class.

Another option is to give both `foo` and `bar` a `*`, and have `foo` both print and save to the `bar` `dest`.  Then `foo` would consume all following strings.  But, if `bar` doesn't have anything to save, it might write `[]` to the namespace.

In any case, the best you can do is fake the repeated use.

---

Another idea is to use 2 different parsers with `parse_known_args`.  Parsers don't mess with the `sys.argv`, so it can read and parsed multiple times.

Comment: I ended up using @9000 solution however thank you for the detailed explaination. A quick note though, optparse seems to be deprecated and recommand to use argparse from now on.

Comment: Based on discussions I've see among developers, I think `optparse` is here to stay for a long time. Official Python tools are slowly switching to `argparse`, but there are lots of other users.  There are certain features of `optparse` that `argparse` can't duplicate because it has a different parsing approach.